# Create Instance of User-Defined Type

Tags: plpgsql, user-defined-types

I'm working on a template script I can give to users and the only thing I want them to touch is in the DECLARE block. The problem is, in the body of the script, I need to perform an operation a variable number of times (in a FOR LOOP). I've created a user-defined TYPE and I'm trying to declare an ARRAY of that type. I think I just don't know the syntax correctly and I've spent a good bit of time searching how to instantiate a variable (or array element) of a user-defined type. The script is several hundred lines long and operates on a handful of variable declarations, but as a simplified example (with comments added inline):

```
CREATE TYPE t_mine AS
(
    key   varchar(50),
    value text
);
```

```
DO
$$
    DECLARE
        setting       t_mine;
        settings      t_mine[] := ARRAY [
            -- This syntax is obviously wrong, I've tried others
            -- with varying results, but all failures
            ('Some', 'Value'),
            ('Another', 'One')
        ];
        error_context text;
    BEGIN
        -- Based on Laurenz' answer, the fix is to change the FOR line to
        -- FOREACH setting IN ARRAY settings
        FOR setting IN SELECT settings
            LOOP
                -- This outputs: Key: {"(Some,Value)"}
                RAISE NOTICE 'Key: %', setting."key";

                -- This outputs: Value: <NULL>
                RAISE NOTICE 'Value: %', setting."value";

                -- Exception raised inside some_operation because
                -- the key is invalid.
                PERFORM some_operation(setting."key", setting."value");
            END LOOP;
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
            GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS error_context = PG_EXCEPTION_CONTEXT;
            RAISE INFO 'Failure';
            RAISE INFO 'Error Name:%',SQLERRM;
            RAISE INFO 'Error State:%', SQLSTATE;
            RAISE INFO 'Error Context:%', error_context;
            ROLLBACK;
    END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The cleaned up log output:

```
[00000] Key: {"(Some,Value)"}
[00000] Value: <NULL>
[00000] Failure
[00000] Error Name:Failed to find the key.
[00000] Error State:P0001
[00000] Error Context:PL/pgSQL function some_operation(character varying,text) line 12 at RAISE
SQL statement "SELECT some_operation(setting."key", setting."value")"
PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 124 at PERFORM
completed in 7 ms
```

Can someone please tell me how to correctly instantiate the user-defined type instances within the array declaration? I need to keep this simple for the users to add/remove/change values and if it's going to be too complex I might as well just have them add/remove/change the `PERFORM some_operation()` calls in the body of the script.

The script calls a bunch of other functions based on logic determined by the variables, but if I can get this working the next step will be to create a new function and the body of this template will simply pass the variables into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your declaration and the assignment there are perfect. The problem is in the loop:

To [loop through an array](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-FOREACH-ARRAY), use

```
FOREACH setting IN ARRAY settings LOOP
```

Comment: Thank you Laurenz. I'm not sure what to do with the first bullet point but the `FOREACH setting IN ARRAY settings` instead of `FOR setting IN SELECT settings` solved the issue!

Comment: Oh, I must have misread your question. Sorry.